# Spring Cloud Gateway global exception handler issue

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using SCG and trying to handle gateway exceptions in one place like I used to do in Spring apps.
I created `GatewayGlobalExceptionHandler` class like this:

```java
    @Configuration
    public class GatewayGlobalExceptionHandler {
      @Bean
      @Order(-2)
      public ErrorWebExceptionHandler errorWebExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        return new JsonExceptionHandler(errorAttributes, objectMapper);
      }
    
      private static class JsonExceptionHandler implements ErrorWebExceptionHandler {
    
        private final ErrorAttributes errorAttributes;
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    
        public JsonExceptionHandler(ErrorAttributes errorAttributes, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
          this.errorAttributes = errorAttributes;
          this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        }
    
        @Override
        public Mono<Void> handle(ServerWebExchange exchange, Throwable ex) {
          int code = 500;
          String message = "An error has occurred";
          if (ex instanceof TotoClientException) {
            code = ((TotoClientException) ex).getCode();
            message = ex.getMessage();
          } else if (ex instanceof TotoServerException) {
            code = ((TotoServerException) ex).getCode();
            message = ex.getMessage();
          }
          exchange.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.valueOf(code));
          exchange.getResponse().getHeaders().setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    
          var responseBody = new ErrorData(code, message);
          try {
            DataBuffer dataBuffer = exchange.getResponse()
                .bufferFactory()
                .wrap(objectMapper.writeValueAsBytes(responseBody));
            return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer)).then();
          } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

ErrorData is a simple record:

```java
    public record ErrorData(int code, String message) {}
```

Doing like this, when I test an endpoint with backend error (4xx or 5xx) using Postman, **I get the expected status code but it keeps waiting forever for the response**.
While doing the same request using a browser, I can see the payload and the status code correctly.